# How to update lookup value in Workflow on CRM dynamics 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I want to update the lookup value in Workflow, all lookup record contains one unique field.

Can we arrange to update the lookup field value for the entity record using unique value of lookup in Workflow.

Suggest me the way that I should not go for plug-in development, and web application development for doing this.

Please can you suggest me for implementing this using workflow under CRM Dynamics 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set a lookup field via the workflow designer to be a particular record.